# C main parameter

Tags: c, parameters, mingw, program-entry-point, wildcard-expansion

I wrote a code which has to display main parameters, but when I compiled it and typed in "*" program shows my file structure.
Command in cmd looks like this: `program.exe 1 2 3 *`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
    for (int i=0; i<argc; i++) printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
program
1
2
3
program.c
program.exe
10-03-20
11-02-20
```

And my question: Is it possible to force program to print "*" instead of listing files.

Comment: The `*` gets interpreted by the shell, not the program itself. Use `\*` or `"*"` to pass the * to the program.

Comment: The problem is that `*` is converted to `"file1 file2 ..."` by your shell. **There is nothing wrong with your C program** (though including `<stdlib.h>` is not necessary). To prevent the shell to convert the *star* use quotes: `program.exe 1 2 3 "*"`

Comment: Not related to the question, but strictly speaking, `char const* argv[]` is not correct. You may not invent forms of main() by yourself, only the compiler may do that. `argv` is actually read/write memory, even though writing to it is often not the best idea.

Comment: I tried `"*"` but I gives the same. I also tried `\*` but this gives `\$Recycle.Bin`

Comment: Hmmm... I can't test Windows' `cmd.exe`, but try `program.exe 1 2 3 '*'`. Also, maybe it can help by itself with `cmd.exe /?`

Comment: The Windows cmd shell doesn't perform wildcard expansion. Either it's not being run from the cmd shell, or the compiler is inserting logic to emulate the expansion the shell would do

Comment: @stasio14, What shell are you using?  What compiler are you using?

Comment: @ikegami I'm using MinGW compiler and cmd shell

Answer (score 7, accepted):

mingw causes the program to perform wildcard expansion of the parameters. Add the following to your program to disable this behaviour:

```c
int _CRT_glob = 0;
```

---

In the unix world, the shell is expected to perform wildcard expansion.

```
$ perl -le'print for @ARGV' *
a
b
```

In the Windows world, wildcard expansion is left to the application.

```
>perl -le"print for @ARGV" *
*
```

That makes writing portable programs tricky. Since mingw is often used to compile programs that weren't written with Windows in mind, its C runtime library performs wildcard expansion of the parameters automatically.

`a.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
    for (int i=0; i<argc; i++)
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

```
>gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors a.c -o a.exe & a *
a
a.c
a.exe
```

But, mingw provides an out. Adding the following to your program disables this behaviour:

```c
int _CRT_glob = 0;
```

`a.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int _CRT_glob = 0; 

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
    for (int i=0; i<argc; i++)
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

```
>gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors a.c -o a.exe & a *
a
*
```